# use variable to access the constructor and obtain intended string

Tags: javascript, jquery, constructor

```
function Title(mainTitle){
  this.mainTitle = mainTitle;
}

var projectTitle1 = new Title("Project-1 Main Title"),
projectTitle2 = new Title("Project-2 Main Title"),
projectTitle3 = new Title("Project-3 Main Title"),
projectTitle4 = new Title("Project-4 Main Title");
```

I like to access the constructor and pull a title relevant to a given index(1-4). I tried the following:

```
  var index = 4,
  x = "projectTitle" + index,
  y = projectTitle.mainTitle;
```

console.log(y) return undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't "access the constructor" after it's run. What you *could* do, however, is to put each instantiation into an array, and access the appropriate index:

```js
function Title(mainTitle){
  this.mainTitle = mainTitle;
}
const titles = [
  new Title("Project-1 Main Title"),
  new Title("Project-2 Main Title"),
  new Title("Project-3 Main Title"),
  new Title("Project-4 Main Title"),
];
const getTitle = titleNum => titles[titleNum - 1].mainTitle;
console.log(getTitle(4));
console.log(getTitle(2));
```

Of course, you'd have to be adding items to `titles` in order. If that can't be relied on, another possibility would be to put each `title` into an *object* indexed by the number in its `mainTitle`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use an array or object.

```
var titles=[
    //add elements here
    new Title("Project-1 Main Title"),
    new Title("Project-2 Main Title")
];
//add a new element after
titles.push(new Title("Project-3 Main Title"));
```

Then access each element by it's index, starting from `0`, `titles[index]`.

Or you could use an object to have a key (property name) for each element.

```
var titles={
    //define elements (properties) here
    "projectTitle1":new Title("Project-1 Main Title")
    "projectTitle2":new Title("Project-2 Main Title")
};
//assign a new element
titles.projectTitle3=new Title("Project-3 Main Title");
```

Then you can access each element as `titles.projectTitle1` or from a string as `titles[x]`.

But you should know why your code doesn't work.

```
var index = 4,
   x = "projectTitle" + index
```

You have `x` with `projectTitle4` as value.

```
y = projectTitle.mainTitle;
```

`projectTitle` is not defined and you never even used `x`.

Having the variable name as string, if that's running in the global scope (outside a function), you can access the variable `projectTitle4` as `window[x]`.

You could easily make your current code work now. But use the array/object way.